# howto get with scanf a string ( char * ) from a user input, delimited by double quotes and containing spaces

Tags: c++, c, windows, dev-c++

I am quite noob with c and c++, and I am stucked trying to read a user input delimited between double quotes for a program I have to deliver to my algorithm class.
The entry would be in this form: "something like this, with spaces, and delimited by this two double quotes". 
What I need to get from that is the string ( char * ) contained between the delimiters.
Unfortunatelly I have been trying without luck to solve this small issue...

The development environment is a virtualized Windows 7 and the ide (both are requirements from the teacher) is DEVC++

Anyone could give a hint or help me out? I am stucked with this and I am running out of time.
thanks in advance!

Comment: Post details of [what you have tried so far](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/). Maybe someone can help you proceed with/correct your approach.

Comment: If you aren't restricted to C rather than C++, as indicated by your tags, why are you using scanf? This is a very strong indicator that the teacher(s) has no clue about C++ (since 1985). There are way too many "C++ teachers" who have no clue, often teaching "C with iostreams" in its place, but in this case it seems even that is skipped.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you have a stream where the current character is a double quote, you can just

1. `ignore()` the current character.
2. `getline()` using `'"'` as the delimiter.

Here is code which skips leading space, verifies that the next character is a `'"'` and, if so, reads the value into `str`:

```
std::string str;
if ((in >> std::ws).peek() == '"' && std::getline(in.ignore(), str, '"')) {
    std::cout << "received \"" << str << "\"\n";
}
```

Comment: thank you very much. I forgot to mention that I have to use scanf to get the string

Comment: You might want to look at the documentation for scanf. The %[^scanset] format may help you read in all characters between double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood the question correctly, then the following suits you. This approach will eliminate every punctuation.

```
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

int main ()
{
  std::string input ;
  std::cout << "Please, enter data: ";

  std::getline (std::cin,input);
  input.erase( remove_if(input.begin(), input.end(), &ispunct),  input.end());
  std::cout << input << std::endl;

  std::cin.get();
  return 0;
}
```

This is the result.

```
>Please, enter data: There' ?are numerous issues. 
There are numerous issues
```

This approach is exactly what you are looking for by using strtok

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

int main() 
{
    char sentence[] = "\"something like this, with spaces, and delimited by this two double quotes\"";  
    char * word;
    std::cout << "Your sentence:\n " << sentence << std::endl;
    word = strtok (sentence,"\"");
    std::cout << "Result:\n " << word << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The result

```
Your sentence:
 "something like this, with spaces, and delimited by this two double quotes"
Result:
 something like this, with spaces, and delimited by this two double quotes
```

Comment: Does not really handle the `"` delimiter issue.

Comment: It does. Run the code and enter the following "There are many problems."  The result is There are many problems

Comment: Ok, addition of the input.erase call looks like it does the trick.